# Como aplicar CSS para elemento HTML antes e depois de um texto?

Tags: css3

Levando em consideração o código HTML abaixo, existe alguma maneira utilizando somente CSS de aplicar estilo diferente para o elemento `i` antes do texto e o outro elemento `i` após o texto?

```
<a href="#">
  <i class="i i--icon"></i>
  Text
  <i class="i i--icon"></i>
</a>
```

Poderia aplicar um `span` ao texto e resolver facilmente isso, porem gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de fazer isso sem adicionar mais código HMTL.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz uma pequena modificação na resposta do @Chun que acabou servindo exatamente para o que precisava:

```
.i--icon {
  &:nth-child(1) {
    margin-right: .5rem;
  }

  &:nth-last-child(1) {
    margin-left: .5rem;
  }
}
```

Eu segui as orientações do [CSS Protips](https://github.com/AllThingsSmitty/css-protips).

Answer (score 3):

Sim, existe. Podes fazer isso utilizando o selector [`:nth-child()`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).
Eis um exemplo abaixo:

```css
i {color:black; font-size: 25px;}
i:nth-child(2) {color: red;}

a {text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <i class="i i--icon">#</i>
  Text
  <i class="i i--icon">#</i>
</a>
```

Neste exemplo acima, o código CSS está a apontar logo diretamente para o elemento `i` porque neste excerto de código HTML não existe nenhuma classe `parent` para apontar de uma maneira mais precisa ao elemento que queremos modificar. Mas num projecto real deveria ser implementada uma class *parent* para termos mais controlo sobre aquilo que queremos modificar e o código ficaria algo mais ou menos deste género: http://jsfiddle.net/z85zhace/

> Podes ler mais sobre o `:nth-child()` em: [CSS3 :nth-child() Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Comment: Legal, não imaginei que seria possível utilizando o `:nth-child()`. Obrigado @Chun!

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar os [pseudo elementos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91528/4808) [**`::after`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter) e [**`::before`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore) para estilizar respectivamente o conteúdo antes e depois de um elemento.

Assim você evita marcações desnecessárias no HTML e não precisa optar por fazer uso do `span` que comentou, o qual não tem relevância alguma para o documento por ser apenas um elemento de natureza "visual".

```css
a { text-decoration: none; color: #333 }

a::after,
a::before {
    content: ' ■ '
}

a::after  { color: #2ecc71 }
a::before { color: #8e44ad }
```

```html
<a href='#'>stackoverflow</a>
```