# Como fazer um checkbox no canto de uma imagem?

Tags: php, html, css

Eu estou a realizar um trabalho para a escola em php, css... E gostaria de saber se é possível colocar *checkboxes* em imagens que vem da base de dados. 
Eu gostaria de colocar as *checkboxes* (em vermelho) como se encontram na imagem anexada. Isto é para facilitar apagar mais que um "evento" ao mesmo tempo

<kbd>[image: ![Resultado esperado]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkcUT.png)</kbd>

<kbd>[image: Meu código]</kbd>

Comment: Por favor, marque minha resposta como aceita, se o código funcionou :)

Answer (score 4):

Antes de responder ao que foi perguntado, uma observação: não é possível estilizar um `input` do tipo *checkbox* apenas definindo a propriedade `background` (ou `background-color`).

Porém existem algumas formas de contornar isso e tratar a questão da cor de fundo:

- Inserir o *checkbox* em um elemento que possui cor de fundo.
- Criar um [pseudo-elemento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91528/4808) com a aparência que está buscando.
- Esconder o elemento de entrada e usar um `<label>` atrelado ao elemento alvo, por meio do atributo `for`. Assim, ao invés de estilizar o `input`, você define as regras de estilo do `<label>`, da mesma forma que é possível [estilizar um input do tipo `file`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91528/4808).

Eu costumo utilizar a terceira opção quando preciso estilizar um elemento desse tipo. Você precisaria alterar um pouco a marcação que está fazendo, para isto:

```
<div class='image-wrapper'>
  <input type='checkbox' id='foo'>
  <label for='foo'>✅</label>

  <img src='http://imgfoo.com/123.png'>
</div>
```

- No `id` do input, você pode ir gerando valores em sequência, por exemplo: imagem1, imagem2, imagem3... Estes valores devem ser únicos.
- No `for` do label, você apontará para o `id` respectivo de cada input.
- E no `src` da imagem você deixará como já está fazendo, inserindo a URL da imagem.

O resultado será esse:

```css
.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px
}

.image-wrapper img {
  width: 100%
}

.image-wrapper input {
  display: none
}

.image-wrapper label {
  background: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 4%;
  top: 4%
}

.image-wrapper input:checked + label {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class='image-wrapper'>
  <input type='checkbox' id='dog-img'>
  <label for='dog-img'>✅</label>

  <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXA8v.jpg'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Antes da linha que retorna a imagem do banco de dados adicione o seguinte código html:

```
<div class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="imgDb" value="imgDb" /></div>
```

ficando assim:

```
echo '<td>
        <a href="desceventos.php?$op='.$img.'" >
            <div class="check">
                <input type="checkbox" name="imgDb" value="imgDb" />
            </div>
            <img heigth="200" width="300" src="data:image;base64,'.$row[1].'" />
        </a>
        </td></tr><tr><td style="float:left,"</td>';
```

Adicione também este css:

```
td{position: absolute}
.check input[type="checkbox"]{
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Isto: `background: red;` não funciona para *checkbox*.