# Como fazer uma barra de progresso que vá de 0 a 100% somente com CSS?

Tags: html, css, css3

Estou desenvolvendo uma página onde tem uma barra de progresso e preciso fazer que ela inicie do 0 e vá ao 100%.

Porém preciso fazer somente com CSS e, além disso, necessito que quando ela chegar ao 100%, inicie novamente do 0.

Apesar de existirem algumas informações sobre essa barra de progresso, eu preciso que ela dure exatamente 6 segundos e quando chegar ao 100%, não volte, pule para o 0%.

Alguém já precisou fazer algo semelhante?

Comment: Só com .css o mais próximo que achei foi isso. https://codepen.io/baletsa/pen/omaHe

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Seria isso, jovem?

```css
.progress{
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #777;
    position: relative;
}

.progress .progress-bar{
   position: absolute;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: #add555;
   animation: progress-animation 6s infinite;
}


@keyframes progress-animation{
    0% { width: 0%; }
    
    100% { width: 100%}
    
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
```

## Explicação

O `@keyframes` tem como finalidade especificar uma animação para o elemento. Você pode definir as etapas para cada frame da animação através de um bloco de estilos CSS declarado através de `from` ou `to`, ou ainda definir através das porcentagens - como fiz acima, indicando que em `0%` (o início) a animação
deverá conter o tamanho `0%` e com `100%` terá `100%` de tamanho.

Exemplo:

```
@keyframes example{
    0% {
        /* frame inicial da animação, poderia ser usado "from" */
    }

   50% {
      /* frame do "meio" da animação */
   }

   100% {
      /* último frame da animação */
   }
```

}

Exemplo com `from`:

```
@keyframes example {
      from {
          /* início da animação */
      }
      to {
         /* final da animação */
      }
}
```

Para usar uma animação declarada com `@keyframes`, você deverá usar o atributo `animation` na definição do seletor desejado, além de poder configurar intervalo da animação ou repetições.

Veja:

```
 .example {
    /* use a animação "example" no intervalo de 2 segundos infinitamente */
    animation: example 2s infinite;
 }
```

**Nota**: A propriedade `animation` é apenas um atalho para as diversas propriedades que podem ser definidas para configurar uma animação. Elas são:

- animation-name
- animation-duration
- animation-timing-function
- animation-delay
- animation-iteration-count
- animation-direction
- animation-fill-mode
- animation-play-state

Leia mais na [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

Answer (score 25):

Minha ideia segue a mesma da [resposta do Wallace](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/262906/4808), com a alternativa de não precisar criar mais de um elemento html para tratar do visual de progresso "interno", a barrinha que vai aumentando a propriedade `width`. Aproveitando o próprio `<div>` e utilizando o [pseudo elemento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91528/4808) [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) (ou [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)) é possível fazer assim:

```css
@keyframes loading {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

div {
  background: #E7E7E7;
  position: relative;
  height: 8px;
  width: 100%
}

div::after {
  animation: loading 6s infinite ease-in-out;
  background: #897FBA;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Eu fui mais rápido :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters danadin +1. :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters foi mais rápido rsrs +1

Comment: @Renan curti a ideia do `::after`, fez com que o elemento ficasse independente.

Comment: e como fazer para que a barra carregue apenas uma vez e mantenha preenchido o progresso quando concluir?

Comment: @WPfan troque a animação de `infinite` para `forwards`: `animation: loading 6s forwards ease-in-out;`.

Comment: @RenanGomes muito obrigado

Answer (score 13):

Tem uma forma diferente de fazer usando `linear-gradiente`, assim não precisa de mais do que uma tag ou de usar *pseudo-elemento*.

Imagine que vc tem um *gradiente linear* como `background` de um *container*, e que esse gradiente é dividido igualmente com 50% da largura com uma cor e os outros 50% com outra cor.

Agora com o `background-size` vc coloca esse `background` com 200% do `width` do *container*. Dessa forma cada metade do gradiente agora ocupa 100% da largura do *container*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora com `background-position` e o `@keyframes` fazemos o `background` andar 100% para um lado, mostrando 100% da outra cor que estava "escondida" fora do *container*.

**A animação**

Sobre a propriedade **`animation`** ela é composta da seguinte maneira no *shorthand*:

```
animation: name duration timing-function delay iteration-count direction fill-mode;
```

Ou no *Longhand* (valores `initial`)

```
animation-name: none
animation-duration: 0s
animation-timing-function: ease
animation-delay: 0s
animation-iteration-count: 1
animation-direction: normal
animation-fill-mode: none
animation-play-state: running
```

No seu caso vc precisa focar no `name` (nome da animação declarado no `@keyframes`), `duration` (tem que vc quer que dure a animação 6s) e `iteration-count` (quantas vezes a animação vai se repetir `infinite` "loop eterno") Nessa documentação da Mozilla vc pode se informar mais: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Depois de definido isso vamos trabalha nos intervalos da animação construídos dentro da *at-rule* `@keyframes`. Como eu quer que vc tenha primeiro um intervalo de 1s para ver a barra 100% vazia no início e depois um intervalo de 1s para vc ver a barra 100% completa no final eu vou repetir alguns valores no início e no final do `@keyframes` Os comentário está no código abaixo:

**OBS:** como a animação tem 6 segundo vou dividir 100 por 6, assim temos 6 intervalos de 16,66% representando cada segundo de animação. No primeiro segundo e no último segundo a barra fica parada por 1 segundo. Se vc não quiser esse efeito basta colocar dessa forma. Assim a barra completa direto, sem um "delay" no inicio e no final pra vc ver os dois estados completos da barra:

```
/* estado inicial da barra */
  0% {
    background-position: 99% 0;
  }
/* estado final da barra */
  100% {
      background-position: 0 0;
  }
```

Para entende melhor como funciona o fracionamento da animação e a criação desse "delay" veja os comentário que deixei no código abaixo:

```css
.barra {
    height: 16px;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin: 10px auto;
 /* gradiente com 2 cores */
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #bada55 0, #bada55 50%, gray 50%);
 /* agradiente com 200% da largura do container 101% pra cada cor */
    background-size: 202% 100%;
 /* move o backgrount para mostrar apenas a primeira cor */
    background-position: 99% 0;
 /* animação que move o background para mostrar a segunda cor */
    animation: anima 6s ease-in-out infinite;
 /* coloquei 500ms de delay para vc poder ver a barra 100% "vazia" antes de iniciar a animação */


}
@keyframes anima {
    0% {
      /* movemo o background para mostrar apenas 100% de uma cor */
      background-position: 99% 0;
    }
    /* do 0% do tempo da animação até 16,66% do tempo a barra permance parada */
    16.66% {
        background-position: 99% 0;
    }
    /* esse intervalo representa 4 segundos do tempo da animação até a barra fica 100% cheia */
    83.34% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    /* esse intervalo de 83,34% a 100% representa 1 segundo da animação e a barra fica cheia por 1s antes de reiniciar*/
    100% {
        /* de 75% a 100% eu repito o estado da propriedade para vc ter um tempo de ver a barra 100% completa antes de reiniciar a animação */
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="barra"></div>
```

---

**Uma imagem para explicar melhor a técnica.**

A borda azul é o *container*, e o fundo se movendo é o `background`. O `background` tem 200% a largura do pai, assim cada cor que tem 50% do gradiente na verdade fica com 100% da largura do pai. Depois ajustando o valor horizontal do `background-position` no `@keyframes` é possível fazer o barra mexendo, dando a impressão que está completando o *container*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Suporte dos browser:*** De acordo com o site https://caniuse.com/ esse modelo funciona do IE10 para cima, Chrome, Fire Fox, Safari, etc...